# Can businesses reclaim a higher VAT rate than applied to the products they sell?

Tags: tax-law, ireland

Take an example where you are a fast food restaurant and you are using an app ("The App") such as Just Eat to handle orders.

Imagine The App charges you a service fee of 20% of the order cost per order, and they add the service VAT rate of 23% on top of this, which makes the total service fee 24.6% of the order cost.

Suppose the VAT rate that you charge your customers is only 9% because food has a reduced VAT rate.

Can you still reclaim the full 23% VAT from the service fee of The App even though you are only passing 9% VAT on to the consumer?

Comment: Good luck https://www.revenue.ie/en/vat/vat-and-financial-services/payment-services/index.aspx

Comment: @StuartF I'm not sure if that link applies to my scenario. This document appears to be for service fees charged solely for the purpose of processing a transfer of money, however I don't think my scenario for an order processing app is limited to that. The app also offers other benefits, such as implicit advertising for the restaurant, order composition functionality for customers, perhaps delivery services, etc.

Comment: I don't see why not. I am not an expert in Irish law of course, but in general a proper VAT is borne by the final consumer depending on the type of final product to be consumed. Businesses are not the target of value-added taxation.